# Image series (animation) over Google Maps

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I'm new to Google map api. My goal is to overlay a series of transparent PNGs over a map over a timespan.

I'm wondering if a purely javascript approach to this is a good start, or if it would be not too hard to do some code behind in asp.net

Also, I'm curious if either google map Api v2.x or v3.x is better suited to this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend avoiding v3 for live sites until its syntax is more stable.

While it's a Google Labs project, Google's policy is that they can make changes to the syntax that will break existing pages with only a few months notice in the discussion group. A while ago they changed the names of all the get_ and set_ methods, and changed some of the event names.

Once the API goes out of Labs and into Beta you can expect Google to take care to preserve backward compatibility whenever they make syntax changes. If you use v3 for a live site while it's still in Labs you'll need to monitor the discussion group for announcements of changes that might break your page.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do it in Javascript, unless you want to reload the page every second or so.  (Which is a *horrible* idea).

You might as well use the latest version of the Google Maps API.