# It is possible to put a animate image on a item of a googlemap? (like a gif)

Tags: android, google-maps

i have an android app with a googlemap view

i have to put an animated icon representing a gps position on the map

i know how to do it with a normal png image, but i want to use something like a GIF image, an animated image

how i can to do it?

EDIT:

THIS IS THE XML ANIMATED: animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/miniicon" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/miniicon2" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/star" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

this is where i asign the XML animated to the drawable

```
//drawable2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.miniicon2); // Icono del programa, para mi posicion GPS
drawable2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.layout.animation); // Icono del programa, para mi posicion GPS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer - there's a similar (but old) question on stackoverflow:

[Image series (animation) over Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633810/image-series-animation-over-google-maps)

which if you look at the accepted answer, provides a demo link.  Some other interesting comments as well.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use an `animation-list` its just a simple xml file that you drop in the drawable folder.  Here is an [example](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/drawable/stat_sys_download.xml;h=77ecf8588b80a0e96cd35d8d4345f17433820891;hb=HEAD), this is the download icon in the notification bar is done.

Comment: and where i have to call that animation-list?

Comment: it doesn't works...... it always shows the first image... i will post the code on first question, see it and tell me if it's wrong please

Comment: you don't 'call' it you just use it as your resource for your drawable.  Just like you would a `selector`

Comment: just like you did above except it should be a drawable not a layout

Answer (score -1):

For sure - OpenGL allows 2D images to be overlayed on top of the image, for one way to do it.  Have a look at [Does Google MapView in Android use OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332837/does-google-mapview-in-android-use-opengl/) for a similar question.

Comment: oh i dont understand that, too munch complicated for me