# Does Google MapView in Android use OpenGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Does Google MapView in Android use OpenGL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not, as far as I can ascertain.  As a side bit of interest, the original google maps was written in C++, but the mobile version was written in Java and intended to run on any phone and platform combination.

However, Android graphics gives you OpenGL capabilities for 2d and 3d graphics, which in theory you could combine with it as an overlay.

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html provides the detail on the MapView class.

If you'd like info on adding an OpenGL SurfaceView to a MapView, have a look at the following question:

[How to overlay GLSurfaceView over a MapView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825539/how-to-overlay-glsurfaceview-over-a-mapview-in-android)

Hope that helps to some extent.